# How to find percentage given mean and standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

The speed limit on Union street is 40 km/h. Rachel and Joe measured the speed of passing vehicles over a period of time. They found the set of data to be normally distributed with a mean speed of 36 km/h and a standard deviation of 2 km/h.
What percentage of the vehicles passed on Union Street at speed greater than 40 km/h?

If μ=36 σ=2
Z=x-μ /σ
so Z=2

Z>2
R(2)=0,02275

So the percentage of the vehicles passed on Union Street at speed greater than 40 km/h is 2,28%

Is the first time that I try to solve this kind of exercise. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have vehicle speeds $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 36, \sigma = 2)$ and
you seek
$$P(X > 40) = P\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} > \frac{40-36}{2}\right)
= P(Z > 2) = 0.02275,$$
where $Z$ has the standard normal distribution and the probability
can be found using printed normal tables or software.

You do not define what you mean by $R,$ but the numerical answer is OK.

---

*Note:* Using some kinds of statistical software you can skip the 'standardization
step' and get the answer directly. In R statistical software, for example,
you could use

```
1 - pnorm(40, 36, 2)
## 0.02275013
```

In Minitab 16 you can get $P(X \le 40)$ and then subtract from $1.$

```
MTB > cdf 40;
SUBC> norm 36 2.

Cumulative Distribution Function 

Normal with mean = 36 and standard deviation = 2

 x  P( X ≤ x )
40    0.977250
```